# fetch works in Node.js and Deno but not in browser or Postman

Tags: node.js, postman, session-cookies, fetch-api, deno

I get an `Unauthorized` error when running this code in the Chrome console (with web security disabled and CSP bypass), but it works fine in Node.js and Deno and Postman, returning the expected JSON object.

Are Node.js and Deno injecting some headers to make it work?

What are they doing differently than the browser's fetch?

I thought they were identical?

```
const profileId = 'foo'; // not real values obviously
const sessionId = 'bar';

getRelativesMetaData(profileId, sessionId).then(console.log);

async function getRelativesMetaData(myProfileId, sessionId) {
  const headers = {
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Cookie': `current-profile-id=${myProfileId}; sessionid=${sessionId}`
  };
  const url = `https://you.23andme.com/p/${myProfileId}/family/relatives/ajax/`;
  const resp = await fetch(url, { headers });
  const json = await resp.json();
  return json;
}
```

Comment: It's just the opposite: `Cookie` is one of the [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), and any compliant browser won't allow you to set this header in your requests. This restriction doesn't apply in environments like Deno and Node because they aren't browsers and it doesn't make sense there.

Comment: Also, unless you're running this code in the browser from inside a `you.23andme.com` web page, there could also be CORs issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the opposite: [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) is one of the [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), and any compliant browser won't allow you to set this header in your requests. This restriction doesn't apply in environments like Deno and Node because they aren't browsers and it doesn't make sense there.

---

Perhaps you are aware that 23andMe does have an [API](https://api.23andme.com/) — but it's restricted-access, which (I guess) is why you are wanting to simply use your session cookie to access your data (presumably in a browser-based web app that you've created). If my intuition about that is correct, then you'll likely benefit from operating a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) using Deno/Node/etc. so that you can get the data in your browser app without needing to worry about auth restrictions in that environment (this also provides the benefit of not exposing your session info in the client app code).